# How to influence the parent result in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

The following GraphQL request:

```
{
  search {
    firstName
    City{
      cityName
    }
  }
}
```

results in:

```
{
  "data": {
    "search": [
      {
        "firstName": "Alice",
        "City": {
          "cityName": "Berlin"
        }
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Bob",
        "City": {
          "cityName": "Madrid"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Adding the firstName argument results in the following;

Request:

```
{
  search(firstName:"Bob") {
    firstName
    City{
      cityName
    }
  }
}
```

In:

```
{
  "data": {
    "search": [
      {
        "firstName": "Bob",
        "City": {
          "cityName": "Madrid"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So far so good, however, if I now add an argument to City, I would like to have this reflect on the complete result.

The following request:

```
{
  search(firstName: "Bob") {
    firstName
    City(cityName: "Madrid") {
      cityName
    }
  }
}
```

Results in:

```
{
  "data": {
    "search": [
      {
        "firstName": "Bob",
        "City": {
          "cityName": null
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But I want the result to be:

```
{
  "data": {
    "search": []
  }
}
```

Or this response:

```
{
  search {
    firstName
    City(cityName: "Madrid") {
      cityName
    }
  }
}
```

should result in

```
{
  "data": {
    "search": [
      {
        "firstName": "Bob",
        "City": {
          "cityName": "Madrid"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I think this has to do with the way the query is structured, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the data resolved by `City(cityName:...)` should not influence `firstName`. Having one field influence the entire response might be a bad structure for the API.

But in order to achieve something like that I would recommend sending cityName param on the `search`, like:

```
{
  search(firstName: "Bob", cityName: "Madrid") {
    firstName
    City {
      cityName
    }
  }
}
```

And resolve that data input on the `search` resolver.

Comment: Aha, thanks. In that case would it be better to introduce it as a filter?

Comment: Yeah, I think that would be the best approach. In that way `search` would control the entire result.